# Return result on conditional format

Tags: excel, vba

Im working on a excel script, that will import a CSV file, analyse the result and create a report based on the analyse.

The CSV file contain up to 12 measurement. and all have to be vertified before the mesurement can be confirmed and end up on the report.

I would like to use conditional format to analyze the result. And need to know if the conditional is OK or not OK.

So my question is: Is there a way to change a boolean, if the conditional goes from FALSE to TRUE using the `FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = True`

Here is a snip of the code.

```
'Add first rule
RangeLength.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
        Formula1:=LengthMin, Formula2:=LengthMax
RangeLength.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
RangeLength.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = True
        If FormatConditions(1) = True Then
            Range("D" & lastRow).Value = True
        End If
```

Edit:

Here are the full sub snip:

```
    Sub MultipleConditionalFormattingExample()



Dim RangeLength As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim LengthMax As Variant, LengthMin As Variant

Set sht = Worksheets("Collection")
lastRow = sht.ListObjects("collectionData").Range.Rows.Count

LengthMax = Worksheets("Engine").Range("G3").Value
LengthMin = Worksheets("Engine").Range("G4").Value

'Create range object
Set RangeLength = Range("G2:G" & lastRow)
RangeLength.Select
'Delete previous conditional formats
RangeLength.FormatConditions.Delete
'Add first rule
RangeLength.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
        Formula1:=LengthMin, Formula2:=LengthMax
RangeLength.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
'Add second rule
    RangeLength.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, _
            Formula1:=LengthMin
    RangeLength.FormatConditions(2).Interior.Color = vbBlue
'Add third rule
    RangeLength.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, _
            Formula1:=LengthMax
    RangeLength.FormatConditions(3).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    RangeLength.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, _
            Formula1:=LengthMax
Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Range("G4").Interior.Color & " should be blue"
Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Range("G5").Interior.Color & " should be red"
Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Range("G8").Interior.Color & " should be yellow"


End Sub
```

And here are the result of the immediate window:

```
16777215 should be blue
16777215 should be red
16777215 should be yellow
```

Hope someone can understand by problem and point me in the right direction.

Thanks
dk.ties

Comment: How do you want to change the condition? What is the result you're looking for? Do you have some data samples that would show all the conditions?

Comment: If you're dynamically applying CF only to validate the data, then on a "pass" copying the data elsewhere, that's a lot of added complication vs. just validating the data using straight VBA.  That said, if after applying the format you want to check if the rule was failed, you'd check that the cell's  `DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` was not `vbRed` [ same as RGB(255,0,0) ]

Comment: Hi both. I posted the question 2 hours before i went on weekend, that why i did not anwser until now.

@TimWilliams: I have allready triede to get the `DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` but it return the same color/color index though its another CF color it have. dunno why. that was also my first idea.  I will update my post with additional code, and also post what i have triede.

dk.ties